# How to shift the reference cell in a formula?

Tags: excel, arguments, formula

How can I turn A1 to G1 in the following formula:

```
=sum(A1+B1)
```

I mean, I want to shift first argument to 5 cell to the right, so that the new formula will be:

```
=sum(G1+B1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shout be the right formula...

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,5),B1)
```